# Google Sheet: If cell contents =A/B/C email address 1/2/3

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

Asked this some time ago, but couldn't get it solved then was on leave for a while.
So will ask again here rather than necro a post.

I've built a holiday request form, and for the most part its finished but I am having a few issues.

I need something that will play out like this:

If contents of latest populated cell in column G = X then email bob@gmail.com and rob@gmail.com, if contents =Y then email frodo@gmail.com and sam@gmail.com, if contentz =z then email dave@gmail.com chez@gmail.com

The sheet is populated by a form, so its updated dynamically. Column G has the shift info for that person, so example if they are on shift 1 then I need it to email the shift manager and supervisor for that shift, if they are on shift 2 then it needs to email a different manager and supervisor. If that makes sense.

I currently have this;

```
var description = supData.getRange(2,1).getValue();
var name = formData.namedValues["Name"];
var startDate = formData.namedValues["Start Date"];
var endDate = formData.namedValues["End Date"];
var to = "frodo@gmail.com";
var subject = "Notice: for " + name + " LEAVE NOTICE (Automail)";
var message = "Leave details: " + "\n" + "\n";
message += description + "\n" + "\n";
message += "The company leave calendar can be viewed by clicking on the following link" + "\n";
message += "https://www.google.com/calendar/b/0/embed?src=gcaladdress@group.calendar.google.com&gsessionid=OK"
MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, message);
```

Which would work perfectly fine if it just needed to be sent to one person, but I need it to be dynamic and am a bit lost in getting it working :S

Answer (score 0):

One way of dealing with this would be to build a [switch statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) with the shift info you get from the from.